# Custom MKOverlayRenderer drawMapRect function not drawing polygons

Tags: ios, swift, mkoverlay

I have built a custom MKOverlayRenderer in order to build polygons, apply a blend mode, then add them to the map view. In my drawMapRect function, I use an array of CGPoints to build the polygon, and create a path.

However, during runtime nothing shows on my map view. My best guess would be the order of which I create the polygon in my drawMapRect function. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
override func drawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, inContext context: CGContext) {

    super.drawMapRect(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale, inContext: context)
    CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Exclusion)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.fillColor)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0)

    let point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(self.polygon.points[0])
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGFloat(point.x), CGFloat(point.y))
    for i in 1..<self.polygon.points.count {
        let point = polygon.points[i]
        let p = MKMapPointForCoordinate(point)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGFloat(p.x), CGFloat(p.y))
    }

    CGContextClosePath(context)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke)
    CGContextRestoreGState(context)
}
```

Here is where my custom overlay renderer is initialized:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if (overlay is MKPolygon) {
        let polygonRenderer = MyCustomMapRenderer(overlay: overlay, fillColor: self.polyFactory!.getPolygonColor().CGColor, polygon: self.currentPolygon!)
        return polygonRenderer
    }
    return MKOverlayRenderer()
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the annotation has been added correctly and that it's a `MKPolygon`? E.g. add breakpoint to `rendererForOverlay` and make sure you're hitting that piece of code. If so, add breakpoint to `drawMapRect` and make sure that's getting called. Sometimes it's something as simple as neglecting to set the delegate of the map view. Let's confirm that's OK before worrying about this code...

Comment: @Rob Yep, they are both definitely getting called. It will hit the `rendererForOverlay's` return before proceeding into `drawMapRect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

- You are taking `points`, which is already an array of `MKMapPoint` (in `MKPolygonRenderer`, at least) and calling `MKMapPointForCoordinate`. If you want to use `MKMapPointForCoordinate`, you'd pass it `coordinates`, not `points`. Maybe you've defined your own properties, but I might change the name of the property to avoid confusion.
- You need to convert map points to screen points with `pointForMapPoint`.
- Also, you are calling `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`, but passing it `fillColor`. But assuming your class is a subclass of `MKPolygonRenderer`, the `fillColor` is a `UIColor`, not a `CGColor`.
- You seem to be accessing some property, `points`, but the `MKPolygonRenderer` doesn't have `points` property, but rather `points()` method.

With all of that said, I'm unclear how your code even compiled. I suspect you didn't subclass from `MKPolygonRenderer`, but rather subclassed `MKOverlayRenderer` and then implemented a bunch of properties yourself? If you subclass `MKPolygonRender`, you get all the polygon behavior for free and only have to implement `drawMapRect`:

```
class MyCustomMapRenderer: MKPolygonRenderer {

    override func drawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, inContext context: CGContext) {
        //super.drawMapRect(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale, inContext: context)

        CGContextSaveGState(context)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Exclusion)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, fillColor!.CGColor)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0)

        if polygon.pointCount > 1 {
            CGContextBeginPath(context)

            let point = pointForMapPoint(polygon.points()[0])
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGFloat(point.x), CGFloat(point.y))
            for i in 1 ..< polygon.pointCount {
                let point = pointForMapPoint(polygon.points()[i])
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGFloat(point.x), CGFloat(point.y))
            }

            CGContextClosePath(context)
            CGContextDrawPath(context, CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke)
        }
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
    }

}
```

By the way, we probably could be more sophisticated here (checking to see if the points were visible, figuring out what points to render given the scale ... i.e. if polygon with thousands of points and being scaled into a 100x100 portion of the view, perhaps you don't have to render all of the points, etc.). See WWDC 2010 [Customizing Maps with Overlays](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2010/127/), which, while dated, is still relevant.

As an aside, your `rendererForOverlay` is curious, too. You are calling some custom initialization method (which is fine), but you're passing `overlay` and `currentPolygon`. But the `overlay` *is* the polygon, so I don't know what this `currentPolygon` is. And `rendererForOverlay` is stateless, so I'd discourage you from referencing some property, but rather just take the `overlay` that was passed to the method. That way, you could have multiple polygons and let map view keep track of which is which. So I'd do something like:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if let polygon = overlay as? MKPolygon {
        let polygonRenderer = MyCustomMapRenderer(polygon: polygon)
        polygonRenderer.fillColor = polyFactory!.getPolygonColor()
        return polygonRenderer
    }
    fatalError("Unexpected overlay type")
}
```

Comment: Well, that certainly did the trick. Thanks @Rob! I believe the problem was that I was subclassing MKOverlayRenderer and just making things more difficult. In switching to subclassing MKPolygonRenderer, things work great! Going forward, I realize many of my property and variable names are somewhat contradictory or overly confusing. I'll definitely rename and refactor those now that the process is working properly. Again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Rob's answer in Swift 4

```
class MyCustomMapRenderer: MKPolygonRenderer {

    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
        //super.drawMapRect(mapRect, zoomScale: zoomScale, inContext: context)

        context.saveGState()
        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.exclusion)
        context.setFillColor(fillColor!.cgColor)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(1.0)

        if polygon.pointCount > 1 {
            context.beginPath()

            let point = self.point(for: polygon.points()[0])
            context.move(to: point)
            for i in 1 ..< polygon.pointCount {
                let point = self.point(for: polygon.points()[i])
                context.addLine(to: point)
            }

            context.closePath()
            context.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fillStroke)
        }
        context.restoreGState()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob's answer in **Swift 3**

```
class MyRenderer: MKPolylineRenderer {

    override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {

        context.saveGState()
        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.exclusion)

        let clear = UIColor.clear

        context.setFillColor(clear.cgColor)

        let green = UIColor.green

        context.setStrokeColor(green.cgColor)

        context.setLineWidth(10.0)

        if self.polyline.pointCount > 1 {

            context.beginPath()

            let point_ = self.point(for: self.polyline.points()[0])

            context.move(to: CGPoint(x: point_.x, y: point_.y))

            for element in 1 ..< self.polyline.pointCount {

                let point_ = self.point(for: polyline.points()[element])

                context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point_.x, y: point_.y))

            }

            context.closePath()

            context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)

        }

        context.restoreGState()

    }


 }
```